# Duplicated border CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `fildset` in my html. It already comes with a default border, but, I was trying to make it less horrible.

It's all going well, except for the `border-color`.

The first time that i aply i didn't realize that my border was *"duplicated"*.

Then, seeing others components with same color, I saw that my `fildset` border was not with the properly color.

[image: This is what i mean duplicated]

This is my css:

```
.tabelaConclusao{
    border-radius: 10px;    
    border-color: #a6c9e2;
}
```

PS: My css looks exacly the same when i use Chromes developer tools.

PPS: In the image, i just change the border width to get bigger, than you can see better what I'm talking about.

Comment: You want to specify a different `border-style` ...

Comment: Please create a [mcve] showing you html and css that recreates your issue

Comment: Looks like an `inset` border to me

Comment: It's a `groove` or `ridge` border. I forget which.

Comment: @ CBroe Facepalm. It work's. Ty!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change border style**

The border-style property sets the style of an element's four borders. This property can have from one to four values.

Form

```
div {
    border-width:5px;  
    border-style:groove;
}
```

To

```
div {
    border-width:5px;  
    border-style:solid;
}
```

[See different/More Border Style](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=double)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `border-style: solid;` that it will work.

Fieldset `border-style` is set by default to `groove`

You can either use the one-line declaration:

```
border: 10px solid #a6c9e2;
```

See the snippet:

```css
fieldset{
    border-radius: 10px;    
    border-color: #a6c9e2;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text"><br>
  Email: <input type="text"><br>
  Date of birth: <input type="text">
 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```